# How can I draw two inequalities with the same constraints without explicitly finding all points?

Tags: inequality, linear-programming

Suppose we have two inequalities combining with the same parameters $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)$:

$x\leq\alpha_1a_1+\alpha_2a_2+\alpha_3a_3$,

$y\leq\alpha_1b_1+\alpha_2b_2+\alpha_3b_3$,

where $a_i, b_i$ are finite constant for all $i=1,2,3$.

However, the $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3$ should satisfy the following constraints:

$\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3\leq \beta$, where $\beta$ is a non-negative finite constant, and

$0\leq\alpha_i\leq\beta_i$ for all $i=1,2,3$, where $\beta_i$ is a non-negative finite constant for all $i$.

Define the collection of all possible points of $(x,y)$ satisfying the two inequalities as $R\in\mathbb{R}^2$. We can be plotted and the outer bound of $R$ can be found by running all possible $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)$. However, the question is:
Can I find the outer bound of $R$ without running all possible $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)$?

My try is: I can prove that the parameters of vertices of $R$ are only possible at $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)\in\{ A$'s vertices}, where $A$ is a set collecting all possible $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)$ satisfying the constraints. But some vertex $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)$ may not be the parameter that a vertex of $R$ has. Therefore, I am wondering if we can explicitly draw $R$ with some inequalities, e.g., a representation of a convex polytope.